# Drop down list with scroll bar, including php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm making a drop down menu where you can select which customer you want to place a specific product or user under. However this list may become several hundred names long, so we need a scroll in it.

Here's the code:

```
<select name="new_customer_id" size="2" style="height:20px;">
    <option value="">Don't link</option>
    <?php 
        $new_customers = User::getCustomers();
        foreach ($new_customers as $customer){
            echo '<option value="' . $customer->id . '">' . $customer->username . '</option>';  
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

But if I use `size='2'`, It switches between either the `'Don't link'`, or the `PHP <option>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just drop size, it will scroll automatically if necessary

Comment: @Jahnux73 Placeholder attribute on a select element?
Not valid according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it... If the select list is too long to fit all entries into the browser window, the browser will automatically render it with a scrollbar. It doesn't matter at all if you create the markup with PHP or not.

You could have just tried that out beforehand... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just drop `size` attribute as `<select>` will automatically scroll if neccessay.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8Tyu/)